# ESRI Field Maps Data Collection Best Practices

Tags: data-collection, arcgis-field-maps

I am trying to determine the best workflow to collect data using ESRI's Field Maps without introducing any unnecessary error. I understand that anytime you complete a datum transformation you are introducing varying degrees of error to your data depending on the specific transformation you choose.

When using Field Maps, the default coordinate system is WGS 84 (Auxiliary Sphere), but my external GPS receiver is set to collect in State Plane coordinates. When I try collect data with this configuration, the data is displaying property in the correct location. So, my question is, what is happening under the hood in Field Maps that allows this to happen?

My main concern is that there is an on-the-fly transformation happening that could be adding a small unnecessary error/shift to my data. According to the source listed below, this transformation would introduce roughly a 0.1 meter shift/error to the data.

Comment: For GPS capture from mobile devices, the device itself is not 10cm accurate (more 30cm in the real world) unless you can guarantee accuracy from higher end chipsets?

Comment: We are currently using the new Leica FLX100 which states that the unit can get as good as 2cm accuracy. I understand that this would be under perfect conditions and perfect conditions are rarely found in the field.

Comment: In new versions the location profile  (optional) can support different coordinate systems https://doc.arcgis.com/en/field-maps/android/help/high-accuracy-data-collection.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_64A6AF2EFEA14F678194AC57FB9BD1B2

Comment: I think the part that I am struggling to understand is... how is the data being displayed properly with field maps being in WGS 84 and my GPS unit set to State Plane? I am not doing anything with the elevation profile. So, is Field Maps transforming the data behind the scenes?